# Which overload is selected when defining an explicit specialization of a function template?

Tags: c++, templates

While reading [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), I'm confused by the following examples:

```
// Example 2: Explicit specialization 
// 
template<class T> // (a) a base template 
void f( T );

template<class T> // (b) a second base template, overloads (a) 
void f( T* );     //     (function templates can't be partially 
                  //     specialized; they overload instead)

template<>        // (c) explicit specialization of (b) 
void f<>(int*);

// ...

int *p; 
f( p );           // calls (c)
```

Here, `(c)` is an explicit specialization of `(b)`.

```
// Example 3: The Dimov/Abrahams Example 
// 
template<class T> // (a) same old base template as before 
void f( T );

template<>        // (c) explicit specialization, this time of (a)
void f<>(int*);

template<class T> // (b) a second base template, overloads (a) 
void f( T* );

// ...

int *p; 
f( p );           // calls (b)! overload resolution ignores 
                  // specializations and operates on the base 
                  // function templates only
```

Here `(c)` is an explicit specialization of `(a)`. Why is that? Is this because of the ordering of the declaration?

Comment: Offhand I'd just say "yes", and assuming the code is valid that's the only possible answer. But the question is whether the second code is valid. I believe it to be valid, but finding this in the standard could be much work...

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: why the second code could not be valid?

Comment: @Donato: disregarding the authors (who Really(TM) know their stuff when it comes to templates) I'm just wary of code that has order-dependent or other more "arbitrary" effect. The standard is designed to protect against such things, to wit, two-phase compilation of templates guards against that kind of thing. So I just have a <0.5% feeling that there just might be some rule about it, then possibly one that doesn't require any diagnostics.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: according to JoshD's answer, this order dependency is he standard, which is odd to me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the ordering of the declaration. When the compiler encounters (c) in the second set, the only defined template to specialize is (a).

This is why you must be careful in ordering your template specializations.

The C++ Programming Language goes into quite some detail about this (Section 13.5.1). I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 9):

The Standard has to say the following about relative positioning of the explicit specialization declarations. [Section `14.7.3`]

> The **placement of explicit specialization declarations for** function templates, class templates, member functions of class templates, static data members of class templates, member classes of class templates, member class  templates  of  class  templates,  member  function  templates  of  class  templates,  member  functions  of member  templates  of  class  templates,  member  functions  of  member  templates  of  non-template  classes,
>   member function templates of member classes of class templates, etc., and the placement of partial specialization declarations of class templates, member class templates of non-template classes, member class templates of class templates, etc., **can affect whether a program is well-formed according to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization declarations and their points of instantiation in the translation unit as specified above and below**.  When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.

Comment: +1 for **self-immolation** - enough to scare away neophytes looking to learn C++

Answer (score 7):

It's the order but it's not *only* the order. For the first code, both templates was defined before. But the second was taken.

This is because the two templates are compared and it is found that `(T)` matches any type that `(T*)` matches, but that `(T*)` does not match all types that `(T)` matches. Thus, the second template is more specialized. Whenever you put an explicit specialization and those two templates match, the templates are compared and the more specialized one is associated by the explicit specialization. This comparison is called "partial ordering".