# Why can function templates not be partially specialized?

Tags: c++, language-design, template-specialization, partial-specialization, function-templates

I know the language specification forbids *partial* specialization of function template.

I would like to know the rationale why it forbids it? Are they not useful?

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U> void f() {}   //allowed!
template<> void f<int, char>()            {}   //allowed!
template<typename T> void f<char, T>()    {}   //not allowed!
template<typename T> void f<T, int>()     {}   //not allowed!
```

Comment: For `template<typename T, typename U> void f(T t, U u) {}` also  `template<> void f(int t, char u) {}` is allowed.

Comment: I find it interesting that people keep providing workarounds when the question is not "how can I achieve a similar goal" but "what's the rationale behind this behavior"... I myself do not know the reason of this choice, but I assume the committee must have had a reason to forbid function template partial specialization. So far the "closest" explanation is the link posted by Georgy, which only points out the potential "risks" of function template partial specialization when overloads are present. However, I don't think that's a reason to forbid this feature, so I assume there is more to this..

Answer (score 60, accepted):

<del>AFAIK that's changed in C++0x.</del>

I guess it was just an oversight (considering that you can always get the partial specialization effect with more verbose code, by placing the function as a `static` member of a class).

You might look up the relevant DR (Defect Report), if there is one.

**EDIT**: checking this, I find that others have also believed that, but no-one is able to find any such support in the draft standard. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716799/partial-specialization-of-function-templates) seems to indicate that *partial specialization of function templates is not supported in C++0x*.

**EDIT 2**: just an example of what I meant by "placing the function as a `static` member of a class":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// template<typename T, typename U> void f() {}   //allowed!
// template<> void f<int, char>()            {}   //allowed!
// template<typename T> void f<char, T>()    {}   //not allowed!
// template<typename T> void f<T, int>()     {}   //not allowed!

void say( char const s[] ) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

namespace detail {
    template< class T, class U >
    struct F {
        static void impl() { say( "1. primary template" ); }
    };

    template<>
    struct F<int, char> {
        static void impl() { say( "2. <int, char> explicit specialization" ); }
    };

    template< class T >
    struct F< char, T > {
        static void impl() { say( "3. <char, T> partial specialization" ); }
    };

    template< class T >
    struct F< T, int > {
        static void impl() { say( "4. <T, int> partial specialization" ); }
    };
}  // namespace detail

template< class T, class U >
void f() { detail::F<T, U>::impl(); }    

int main() {
    f<char const*, double>();       // 1
    f<int, char>();                 // 2
    f<char, double>();              // 3
    f<double, int>();               // 4
}
```

Comment: do you have the standard in n3225 ? I did a quick search but could not find it :/

Comment: ah sorry... a word was missing. I have the document, but could not find the particular *paragraph*. Though given your edit, I guess it's simply because it's not in there :)

Comment: This is not changed in C++0x. I also doubt its utility. You can always overload the template and make use of partial *ordering*.

Comment: Late update: did not change even in C++17 eight years later, and doesn't seem to enter C++20 either. Cannot see any reason for, though...

Comment: This is by far the most comprehensive implementation of the concept, I believe

Answer (score 21):

Well, you really can't do partial function/method specialization however you can do overloading.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T fun(U pObj){...}

// acts like partial specialization <T, int> AFAIK 
// (based on Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu)
template <typename T>
T fun(int pObj){...}
```

It is the way but I do not know if it satisfy you.

Comment: Wow my mind was filled with templates such that I really forgot how simple things could be :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the case when you want to pass variadic arguments after partially specializing the function.. :(

Comment: Im not sure what was meant by passing variadic templates, so I'd like to know how it is different from a partial specialization. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: What if you want just two functions for all integral and float types?

Answer (score 15):

In general, it's not recommended to specialize function templates at all, because of troubles with overloading. Here's a good article from the C/C++ Users Journal: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

And it contains an honest answer to your question:

> For one thing, you can't partially specialize them -- pretty much just because the language says you can't.

Comment: The article is not about partial specialization besides that it is mentioned once.

Answer (score 11):

Since you can partially specialize classes, you can use a functor:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename dtype, int k> struct fun
{
    int operator()()
    {
        return k;
    }
};

template <typename dtype> struct fun <dtype, 0>
{
    int operator()()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main ( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
     std::cout << fun<float, 5>()() << std::endl;
     std::cout << fun<float, 0>()() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can then use a single function template to make the calls, getting rid of the ugly `()()` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Partial specializations of function templates would be extremely problematic for two reasons.

#### Syntactical ambiguity with function template overloading

Consider the syntax of a full specialization:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(T);

template <>
void foo(int); // full specialization; we could optionally write foo<int>(int)
```

From the `template <>` syntax, it is clear that this is a full specialization, not a non-template overload.
However, it would not be so clear for a partial specialization:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(std::complex<T>);
```

This could either be interpreted as a second overload, or as a partial specialization `foo<std::complex<T>>(std::complex<T>)`.
This ambiguity would be extremely confusing if it existed in the language.

Even full specializations can be confusing when there are multiple overloads; see [Which overload is selected when defining an explicit specialization of a function template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3935421/5740428)

#### Specializations don't participate in overload resolution

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo();                                   // (0) primary template

template <>
void foo(std::complex<int>);                  // (1) full specialization

template <typename T>
void foo(std::complex<T>);                    // (2) overload
```

If we call this with an argument of type `std::complex<int>`, then (2) is called, not (1), because specializations don't participate in overload resolution. This is counter-intuitive because `std::complex<int>` is "more specialized" than `std::complex<T>`.

Full specializations and hypothetical partial specializations of function templates behave contrary to intuition. Function template overloading is a much more useful feature, and should be preferred in most cases.

#### Workaround - Overloading, or partial specializations of class templates

In most cases, you can simply use function template overloading instead.
If you need to closely imitate partial specializations, you can write function objects instead:

```cpp
// primary template
template <typename T>
struct foo_object {
    void operator()(T) const { /* ... */ }
};

// partial specialization
template <typename T>
struct foo_object<std::complex<T>> {
    void operator()(std::complex<T>) const { /* ... */ }
};

// convenience function
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    return foo_object<T>{}(t);
}
```

It may seem pointless compared to function template overloading at first, but partial specializations can delegate to each other through inheritance, which may be useful.

Such a pattern is a viable alternative to tag dispatch.

#### See Also

Herb Sutter's article [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) explains issues regarding explicit specializations in great detail. Those equally apply to hypothetical partial specializations.