# unable to specialize template function for both vector and abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, vector, specialization

I'm trying to write a template function, but I have trouble specializing it for vector<> and another class at the same time. Here is the code I'm using :

```
// template definition
template< class T >
void f( const T& value) 
{
    cout << "DEFAULT" << endl;
}

// specialization for MyClass
template< class T >
void f<>  ( const MyClass & value )
{
    cout << "MyClass" << endl;
}

// specialization for vector
template< class T >
void f<>( const std::vector<T> & v )
{
    cout << "vector" << endl;
}
```

`MyClass` and `MyClass2` are defined as:

```
class MyClass{
virtual void a() = 0;
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass{
    void a(){}
};
```

Finally, the `main` function:

```
int main(int nArgs, char *vArgs[]){

    MyClass2 e;
    f<MyClass>(e);

}
```

Here is the error I get when I try compiling it using Visual Studio 2010:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(869): error C2259: 'MyClass' : cannot instantiate abstract class

This seems to be very specific to this particular situation: As soon as I remove the `const` modifiers, I change the `vector` into a `list` or I make `MyClass` concrete, everything works. But for my problem I need for this particular situation to work.

Is anybody having the same error as me, and more importantly does anybody know a fix/workaround for this?

Comment: `template< class T > void f<>  ( const MyClass & value )` and `template< class T > void f<>( const std::vector<T> & v )` are incorrect lines of code.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: It is not correct syntax for specializations. Where did you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this:

```
// specialization for vector
template< class T >
void f<>( const std::vector<T> & v )
{
    cout << "vector" << endl;
}
```

is not possible (even if your syntax were corrected, as Anton did in his answer), because it is not a full specialization of `f` (there are unbound type parameters). Partial function specialization is not allowed under the C++ standard.

There are a few other questions on Stack Overflow involving similar code with similar issues. This one (and the winning answer) seems to be quite relevant: [Why function template cannot be partially specialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101516/why-function-template-cannot-be-partially-specialized)

You can peruse the C++ standards for yourself, if you were feeling particularly masochistic. You might start from section 14.7.3 ("Explicit specialization") at page 368 of this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf (which is a semi-recent draft, but not the most up to date. It is free, however.)

Comment: I think you find the root cause : "Partial function specialization is not allowed under the C++ standard". Still I'm wondering why when I change the vector into a list in the specialized function parameter, my code compiles fine, and I'm able to call `f<MyClass>(e)`. I suppose you would say that it's "by chance"?

Comment: @ArthurBall I'm really not at all sure why the `list` specialisation works, and the `vector` one doesn't. I'd be tempted to chalk it up to some particular quirk of VS 2010; it has an awful lot of those (the code is describing nonstandard behaviour, after all). I'm not able to acutally instantiate a `list<MyClass>` under VS 2010, however... that does seem like a specific compiler or library issue as other compilers manage that bit okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in specialization syntax.

Probably, it should look like this:

```
// MyClass
class MyClass{
virtual void a() = 0;
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass{
    void a(){}
};

// template definition
template< class T >
void f(const T& value)
{
    cout << "DEFAULT" << endl;
};

// specialization for MyClass
template<>
void f(const MyClass & value)
{
    cout << "MyClass" << endl;
};

// specialization for vector of MyClass
template<>
void f(const std::vector<MyClass> & v)
{
    cout << "vector" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Using template for any type
    f(2);

    // Using specialization for MyClass
    MyClass2 e;
    f<MyClass>(e);

    // Using specialization for vector<MyClass>
    vector<MyClass> vM;
    f(vM);
}
```

Comment: I can't compile your code, MyClass is abstract and I can't instantiate it in a vector.

Comment: I added MyClass to the sample. Now it should be compiled. You don't need to instantiate it in the vector

Comment: Although this code works fine for me under GCC 4.7.2 and VS 2013, it will not build under VS 2010, and so has the same issues the OP reported originally.

Comment: `std::vector` with elements which type is an abstract class? Looks like incorrect code...

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have indicated:

- your syntax for specialization is wrong
- you cannot partially specialize a template function

> ...does anybody know a fix/workaround for this?

Since you are using the template argument in the argument list, you can use overloaded functions.

```
template <class T>
void f(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << "DEFAULT" << std::endl;
}

void f(const MyClass& value)
{
    std::cout << "MyClass" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void f(const std::vector<T>& v) // this is an overload, not a specialization
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(1);
    MyClass2 e;
    f(e);
    f(std::vector<int>());
}
```

Comment: You're right, the `vector` version of my function is not a specialization, it is an overload. Though, I find it weird that partial specialization works fine for classes and not for functions.

Comment: @ArthurBall I don't think it would play well with overload resolution. Besides, functions and classes are different things, so template functions and template classes are too. It's also not possible to deduce the template argumemnts of a class, e.g. when calling a constructor. I miss that more than partial specialization of template functions.