# Specializing a function of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

This is legal in C++:

```
template <int N> class A {
    void bar() {std::cout << N << '\n';}
};

template<>
void A<2>::bar() {std::cout << "Two\n";}  // This is ok.
```

Now consider this class:

```
template <int...> struct B;

template <int First, int... Rest>
struct B<First, Rest...> : B<Rest...> {
    static void foo() {
        std::cout << First << ' ';
        B<Rest...>::foo();  
    }
    static void bar() {/*Bunch of code*/}
    static void baz() {/*Bunch of code*/}
};

template <>
struct B<> {
    static void foo() {}
    static void bar() {}
    static void baz() {}
};
```

Then why is the following illegal (placed after the above):

```
template <int... Rest>
void B<2, Rest...>::foo() {  // Illegal.
    std::cout << "Two ";
    B<Rest...>::foo();
}
```

I don't see why `B<2, Rest...>` is an incomplete type, as the error message states.  So apparently, the only way to achieve what I want is through this?

```
template <int... Rest>
struct B<2, Rest...> : B<Rest...> {
    static void foo() {
        std::cout << "Two ";
        B<Rest...>::foo();  
    }
    static void bar() {/*Same bunch of code as above*/}
    static void baz() {/*Same bunch of code as above*/}
};
```

Thus repeating all the code in bar() and baz()?

Comment: The first is an explicit specialization (which is OK); the second would be a partial specialization (which isn't).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called partial template specialization, and is allowed only for classes, not for functions. See for example [Why function template cannot be partially specialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101516/why-function-template-cannot-be-partially-specialized)

Comment: I knew that rule, but I thought the partial specialization here was more to do with the class than the function.  After all, the error message was pointing at `B<2, Rest...>` being an incomplete type.  So there is no satisfying workaround, is there?

Comment: That link isn't relevant to this question - OP isn't trying to partially specialize a function template.

Comment: But people are voting that I am.  I also thought I wasn't trying to partially specialize a function template before posting my question.